# Assigning a numeric/epoch value to scheduled_at is deprecated in Rails 7.1.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm getting a deprecation warning when upgrading to Rails 7.1 and Google has no search results!

The warning is `DEPRECATION WARNING: Assigning a numeric/epoch value to scheduled_at is deprecated. Use a Time object instead.`

This is raised when we're scheduling a background job using `wait_until`. They value we're passing in our tests is `1.month.from.now` which gives a time value.

Line which I think raises warning:

```
NotifyAudienceJob.set(wait_until: published_at).perform_later(audience.id)
```

and the test which triggers the warning:

```rb
  test 'creating audiences for a scheduled article with notifications enabled should schedule notifications' do
    @article.update!(published_at: 1.month.from_now)

    assert_enqueued_with(job: NotifyAudienceJob) do
      post admin_news_feed_article_audiences_url(@article), params: { whole_organisation: true }
    end
  end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the fix for this might be?

The warning is [from this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6c9967f85ada90f8ca58e794a850e887ceb45132/activejob/lib/active_job/core.rb#L177) in ActiveJob

Note: This is fixed in Rails 7.1.0.rc2

Comment: An `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance is not a numeric/epoch value. The change is from 2 days ago. To me, it looks like they forgot to add their own time class :)

Comment: BTW probably using callback is not good idea for this purpose. I would make some scheduled job (1 per N period) and check something like `Article.where(published: false).where('published_at > now()').find_each { |id| NotifyAudienceJob.perform(id) }`

Comment: has been [fixed in rails proper](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/32eba97a08593c833db35b46cd3e0f1f8fcd3ef6): "When the `:at` attribute is sent to the test adapter it is converted
to a float, and that float is what is added to the payload, so we
need to convert back to a Time object."

Answer (score 2):

Convert this object to `Time` object as mentioned

```rb
1.month.from_now.to_time
```

Now it is not `Time` object

```rb
1.month.from_now.class # => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
1.month.from_now.to_time.class # => Time
```